# Missing right parenthesis at line 1

Tags: oracle

So i'm very new to oracle just doing it for my assignment. i created a table before and it was created successfully. Now i'm creating an other table and i want to give eid the reference of my first table but it is giving me the error of missing right parenthesis. I searched it but couldn't solve it. Please help me for the sake of my assignment.

```
Create Table Tab2 (eid number reference tab1 (eid), address1 varchar2 (25), address2 varchar2 (15));
```

Comment: use `references` instead of `reference`

Comment: thankyou very much @Utsav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, use `REFERENCES`

```
CREATE TABLE Tab2 
(eid number REFERENCES tab1 (eid),
address1 varchar2 (25),
address2 varchar2 (15)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table Tab2 (eid number references tab1 (eid), address1 varchar2 (25), address2 varchar2 (15));
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Oracle!

What are you using to work with the database? SQL*Plus? SQL Developer?

If you're using SQL Developer, it can help you answer these questions.

[image]

Comment: im using SQL*PLUS

Comment: Since you're new, I suggest you try SQL Developer first. You'll still learn the language, but you'll progress much faster.

Comment: thankyou very much.. and i still need your help. i'm trying to run sql developer.it ask for java path when i provide the path it gives me the error of " unable to find java virtual machine for sql developer " i looked for the solution it states "Remove the complete line starting with " SetJavaHome " " in sqldeveloper.conf file. when i do that and try to save the file after editing it again gives me the error of access denied

Comment: um, what OS, and what version of sqldev and Java are you using? If on windows just grab the build that includes the JDK, zero setup/config required

Comment: im using the latest version of sqldev i downloaded it from the oracle site i guess!! can provide you the link from where i downloaded it

Comment: yeah, bc you didn't answer my question. we have a beta, v4.2 with a known issue with the EXE finding the embedded JDK, and a zero issues official 4.1.5 release - i need to know which one you have